# « Lien », « liaison » et « rapport »

Tags: usage, synonymes

Je me demande s'il y a des cas dans lesquels les mots *lien*, *liaison* et *rapport* peuvent être employés interchangeablement, à savoir, l'un à la place de l'autre ; par exemple *liaison* à la place de *lien* et vice versa.

Comment: Bonjour, serait-il possible de donner un exemple ou plus de détails à propos de votre sujet, je ne suis pas sûr d'avoir bien compris la question.

Comment: @Ced Merci pour le commentaire. Je me demande (sachant les sens voisins des mots) s'il existe des cas que l'on peut employer l'un à la place de l'autre indifféremment. Contre-exemple :  On dit liaison pour le phénomène linguistique et pas lien.  Alors ici lien ne peut remplacer liaison. Ça je sais:-)!

Comment: Votre femme peut avoir des *liens* avec un autre homme sans avoir de *liaison* ni de *rapports*. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une question similaire a été postée sur [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/737e3s/whats_the_difference_between_lien_liaison_and/). Cependant, l'explication est en anglais.

- Un **lien** est défini par une relation entre des personnes (lien physique), mais peut également être défini par la liaison entre un événement et sa cause. En d'autres termes, un lien permet d'attacher, d'unir, de lier.

> J'ai un *lien* de parenté avec cette jeune femme.

*Cela signifie que j'ai une relation avec jeune femme, c'est une personne qui fait partie de ma famille (lien physique). Dans cette situation, je ne peux pas remplacer le mot **lien** par **liaison**, car nous n'entretenons pas de relation amoureuse ou sexuelle. De plus, le mot **rapport** pourrait être utilisé, mais de manière générale dans la langue cela ne se dit pas.*

- Une **liaison** est définie par une union entre deux éléments, par exemple une relation amoureuse ou une relation sexuelle.

> Ma copine et moi entretenons une bonne liaison.

*Cela signifie que notre liaison est très forte, d'un point de vu amoureux. Ici, nous pouvons éventuellement utiliser le mot **lien**.*

> Ma copine et moi entretenons un lien très fort.

*L'utilisation du mot **rapport** n'aurait pas trop de sens, sauf pour dire que les deux individus entretiennent des rapports sexuels fort. Bref, ceci n'a pas trop d'intérêt.*

- Un **rapport** est défini par une relation entre des personnes ou des groupes. Il est également utilisé pour reconnaître ou rejeter l'importance de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un dans une situation.

> J'entretiens de bons rapports avec mes collègues de travail.

*Cela signifie que j'ai de bons liens avec mes collègues de travail, nous nous entendons bien ensemble. Ici, nous pouvons remplacer le mot **rapport** par **lien**, mais pas par **liaison**, car en bon français cela ne se dit pas.*

Autre exemple avec le mot **rapport**

> Il me racontait une histoire à propos d'un tueur en série lorsque soudain, il me demanda : "tu veux manger une bonne pizza ?" Je lui répondais : "Quel est le rapport ?"

*Dans ce cas de figure, le mot **rapport** peut être remplacé par **lien**, car on peut se demander :*

> Quel est le lien entre l'histoire et manger une pizza ?

*On peut également remplacer **rapport** par **liaison** car on peut dire :*

> Explique-moi la liaison qu'il y a entre ton histoire et le fait de manger une pizza ?

Quel que soit le mot que tu utilises (lien, liaison ou rapport), il est difficile de dire si l'un est interchangeable avec un autre. Cependant, avec les exemples que je viens de donner, il y a des cas de figure où tu peux changer l'un avec un autre, mais des fois, il faut changer la tournure de ta phrase.

Comment: Excellente réponse ! Merci.

Comment: @dimitris Un plaisir :)

Answer (score 2):

On aurait pu ajouter les mots « ligature », « connexion » et « relation » à la liste ; sans ces additions le sujet est déjà très compliqué et on ne peut espérer plus des lignes qui vont suivre qu'un petit aperçu plus ou moins chaotique de la question.

Le lien est la chose concrète ou abstraite qui matérialise un rapprochement plus ou moins fixe ou une communication, ou encore un rapport de cause à effet  ; cependant, c'est aussi quelque chose qui est soit la conséquence de l'état  naturel soit la conséquence d'un acte de liaison par l'homme (et par l'animal devrait-on dire, pollinisation, régulation hydraulique par les castors, etc.) ; la liaison est d'une part une opération au moyen de laquelle est établie un rapprochement, une communication, un rapport de cause à effet où « normalement » on n'en trouve pas et donc une opération au moyen de laquelle est établi un lien et c'est d'autre part le résultat de cette action, un système ; c'est aussi l'état d'être lié (mais pas dans tous les contextes). Par exemple, il y a un lien entre le prix de revient à la consommation et le prix de la matière première (évident) ; mais, en passant maintenant au domaine de l'administration, on dit « il y a une liaison entre le Ministère des Finances et le Ministère de l'Économie en vue produire certains effets sur l'industrie » plutôt que « il y a un lien ». On n'utilisera « lien » dans ce cas que si l'on veut référer au fait qu'il existe une connexion en général, que si l'on veut référer aux rouages, mais dans le cas spécifique où l'on sous-entend un système de communication et d'action concertée le mot « liaison » est celui qui convient. Ce principe concernant les systèmes humains du type « lien » qui implique communication et action concertée est généralement respecté (liaisons interarmées, liaisons commerciales, …).

La différence centrale que l'on doit faire entre « lien » et « liaison » est celle-ci : le lien est une chose, ce qui est lié au moyen du lien une autre, l'ensemble des choses liées et du lien constituant une liaison ; une pièce métallique qui raccorde deux poutres constitue un lien, l'ensemble du lien et des parties de poutre où il fait effet est une liaison ; plus généralement on parlera de l'ensemble des deux poutres ainsi liées en tant que la liaison de deux poutres, soit pour en constituer une plus longue, soit pour créer une structure de support d'un autre type. Ce principe est cependant soumis à l'existence d'un contexte particulier, celui des systèmes naturels ou artificiels.

Dans le cas de prisonniers attachés à des poteaux par des cordes, lesquelles on appelle toujours des liens, on ne parle pas de liaison parce que le poteau, le prisonnier et les cordes ne sont pas un système. Dans le cas très similaire des tuteurs que l'on utilise pour diriger la croissance des plantes le mot « liaison » redevient utile ;

- Cette liaison du tronc et de son tuteur ne peut être faite qu'avec un matériaux suffisamment expansible.

« Lien » n'est pratiquement pas un *synonyme spécifique* de « liaison » sauf dans les cas suivants ;

**1.** INFORMAT.  Séquence d'instructions reliant deux parties d'un programme`` (BUREAU 1972). Synon. liaison.

**2.** ARTILL. Lien élastique. Pièce reliant la bouche à feu à l'affût du canon. L'usage a consacré le terme de liens ou liaisons élastiques pour désigner les ressorts et les freins hydrauliques [destinés à limiter le recul] (ALVIN, Artill., Matér., 1908, p. 162).

Les mots « liens » et « ligature » sont souvent utilisables de façon synonymes pour le concept concret d'attache physique.

Deux contextes dans lesquels on mentionne une liaison sans s'étendre sur le lien

- (TLFi) Il existe une **liaison** très intime, et même souvent une continuité non interrompue entre les filons et autres dépôts d'incrustation formés à l'intérieur du sol déjà consolidé et des couches métallifères dans lesquelles les mêmes substances se trouvent disséminées. (ÉLIE DE BEAUMONT ds B. Sté géol. Fr., t. 4, 1847, p. 35)
- (TLFi) La principale chose à considérer ici, c'est cette **liaison** de tous les muscles qui fait que chacun d'eux, dès qu'il se remue, éveille tous les autres, et non point d'abord ceux qui doivent coopérer. (ALAIN, Propos, 1921, p. 349)

« Rapport » sera souvent un synonyme de « lien » dans la partie des concepts abstraits auxquels le terme « lien » est applicable. Par exemple, dans le cas des prix considéré ci-dessus il n'y a aucun problème dans le remplacement de « lien » par « rapport », et évidemment, vice-versa. Dans le second exemple considéré, ce n'est plus vrai. « Rapport » ne peut en aucun cas être utilisé pour les liens en tant que ligatures, c'est à dire comme instruments matériels de réalisation d'attaches ;

> (TLFi)
>   1. [Dans l'ordre logique] Élément qui réunit, rattache deux ou plusieurs choses entre elles, assure leur relation, les met en **rapport**; le **rapport** lui-même tel qu'il est perçu par l'esprit.
>   3. SYNT. Lien commun, continu, direct; lien réel, apparent, artificiel; lien causal, logique, nécessaire, historique; lien de causalité, de nécessité, de dépendance, de subordination; être, constituer, former un lien; faire le lien entre deux choses; idées, faits, mots sans lien.
>   2. [Dans l'ordre des **rapports** humains.]
>   a) Ce qui unit deux ou plusieurs personnes (ou groupes de personnes), établit entre elles des relations d'ordre social, moral, affectif p. ex.; les relations ainsi constituées.

Dans les contextes suivants on ne remplace pas « lien » par « rapport » sauf exceptionnellement (se délivrer, s'affranchir de ses rapports; être libre de tout rapport) ;

> (TLFi, suite)
>   b) Ce qui attache moralement quelqu'un à quelque chose.
>   c) Ce qui met dans une situation de dépendance, ce qui contraint, enchaîne, asservit.
>    Les liens de l'habitude, de la raison, de la conscience, de la morale; être dans les liens de qqn, de qqc.; tenir qqn dans ses liens; se délivrer, s'affranchir de ses liens; être libre de tout lien.

Le domaine des liens affectifs réunit  les concepts de « lien » et de « liaison » de façon à causer le contexte d'un apparent manque de différentiation ; les liens affectifs sont les liens de l'amour filial, parental, amical et d'autres probablement, moins évidents et que je ne peux identifier au moment présent ; cependant, le lien qui se développe à travers l'attraction des sexes opposés donne lieu à un terme qui n'est plus le lien mais la liaison ; on pourrait donc croire sans trop penser à la question que la différence habituelle n'est pas faite ; mais ce n'est pas la réalité ; on ne considère pas ce rapport sous l'aspect du lien, qui est tout simplement le lien de l'amour et qui n'est nullement particulier en tant que lien (c'est très similairement le lien de l'amour conjugal) mais on le considère sous l'aspect d'un système de relations humaines. Le terme neutre, liaison, peut alors prendre des connotations négatives ; c'est seulement le cas lorsque il est appliqué à une personne qui est déjà mariée.